# Retrieval of items from custom collection

Tags: c#, collections

I have a following class

```
public class People
{
    public int id;
    public string nameHash;
    public string name;
}
```

I need to create a custom collection, consisting of objects of class `People`, that lets me retrieve elements by its `id` and `nameHash`. The collection must have the ability to iterate through its elements using foreach:

```
foreach (People person in PeopleCollection) { ... }
```

How do I do that? If you can not give a detailed answer, at least give a brief plan of action. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mark this as homework if it is.

Comment: Added homework tag based off of OP comments below.  Appears to have been a test question; not sure if school or job related

Comment: Yes, homework. Sorry, I am new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a large collection and you want faster lookups based on an integer `Id` or a string `NameHash` field while still supporting the `foreach (Foo f in fooCollection)` pattern, then you can roll your own collection that wraps a pair of dictionaries. Crude implementation, not thoroughly tested:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string NameHash { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person(int id, string nameHash, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        NameHash = nameHash;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class People : IEnumerable<Person>
{
    private Dictionary<int, Person> personDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
    private Dictionary<string, int> hashIdMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("person");

        if (personDictionary.ContainsKey(person.Id))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("person Id is already referenced in collection.");

        if (hashIdMap.ContainsKey(person.NameHash))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("person NameHash is already referenced in collection.");

        personDictionary.Add(person.Id, person);
        hashIdMap.Add(person.NameHash, person.Id);
    }

    public Person this[int id]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!personDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Id is not in the collection.");

            return personDictionary[id];
        }
    }

    public Person this[string nameHash]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!hashIdMap.ContainsKey(nameHash))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("NameHash is not in the collection.");

            return this[hashIdMap[nameHash]];
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Person> pair in personDictionary)
            yield return pair.Value;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

...

```
static void Main()
{
    Person personA = new Person(1, "A", "Apple");
    Person personB = new Person(2, "B", "Banana");
    Person personC = new Person(3, "C", "Cherry");

    People people = new People();
    people.Add(personA);
    people.Add(personB);
    people.Add(personC);

    Person foo = people[1];
    Person bar = people["C"];

    Debug.Assert(foo.Name == "Apple");
    Debug.Assert(bar.Name == "Cherry");

    foreach (Person person in people)
        Debug.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Of course, if you're dealing with a small-ish collection, you could very well simply use a `List<T>` and utilize either LINQ or the `Find` methods already defined. Such as

```
Person personA = collection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 42);
Person personB = collection.Find(p => p.NameHash == "Blah");
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for taking your time to write it!

Answer (score 3):

Is there a specific reason why it has to be a custom collection?
Why not

```
List<People> PeopleCollection = new List<People>();
```

you can retrieve elements using `id` and `nameHash` and you can iterate over `PeopleCollection`

Comment: Are you leaving it up to him to use Linq / `Find` / other methods for retrieving items by either the `id` or `nameHash` fields? A custom collection could be crafted to support fast lookups for one or both of these pieces of information (depends upon his particular usage scenario as to what may be warranted).

Comment: Anthony, it is not a real life scenario, it is a test program that I have to write. It also mentions that "the access time to collection elements via id and nameHash  is critical" - Max

Answer (score 2):

```
class PeopleList : List<People> {

}
```

That's pretty much it. Just inherit from `List<T>` and you're set.

BTW, you should reconsider your naming conventions. 'People' is not a good name for a class that represents a single person. Name it 'Person' instead, and name your list 'People'.

Comment: Are you leaving it up to him to use Linq / `Find` / other methods for retrieving items by either the `id` or `nameHash` fields? A custom collection could be crafted to support fast lookups for one or both of these pieces of information (depends upon his particular usage scenario as to what may be warranted).

Comment: There is no custom collection here to speak of, I just recommended he inherit from List<T>.

Comment: Yes, I agree about the naming, but that is an exam question that I was given

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here:

1. Inherit from an existing collection type, as shown in other answers.
2. Implement the [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) or [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface, which also means writing your own implementation of [`System.Collections.IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) or [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx)